# Having trouble discovering a way to make a calendar using Python

Tags: python

I need to make a calendar in Python that displays a formatted table of a month when the user inputs the days in the month and the date of the first Sunday. For example, if user inputs 30 days and the first Sunday is 6, then the calendar would look like this.

[image: Calendar]

I have no idea which direction to go when going about this problem. I could use some help on how to approach this question. So far I've only learnt about booleans, conditionals, loops, etc. Also not allowed to import calendar. Thank you.

Comment: Should your code also detect the month and year and print accordingly ?

Comment: Are you allowed to import PIL or any other PNG image library, or are you supposed to create a PNG out of nothing? Can you use existing font libraries? (If not: cheat and use a font library to create bitmaps for the characters in the sizes you need; then include only those in your source.)

Comment: **@Blooper**, can you please check and give feedback if my answer satisfies you or not. If not, please suggest the edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if this meets the need

```
day_count=30
first_sunday=6

if first_sunday != 1:
    i=int(first_sunday)-7
else:
    i=1

count=1
print "Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa"
while i<=day_count:
    if i<1:
        print ("%-3s" % (" ")),
    else:
        print ("%-3s" %  (str(i))),
    if i>0 and count % 7 == 0:
        print ""
    i=i+1
    count = count+1
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Blooper**, I've written the below code in which the function **show_formatted_calendar()** that takes 5 parameters.

First 2 are required parameters & last 3 are optional parameters that you can pass if you want to change the look of your table.

In the code, I've called the **show_formatted_calendar()** 3 times.

> **show_formatted_calendar()** returns a formatted calendar string that you can print on console, save in file or store in variable for reuse.

If you run it, it will ask you to enter the values of first 2 required parameters and uses default values for last 3 parameters (in first call).

In 2nd and 3rd calls it takes static calls for first 2 parameters and overrides the default values of the last 3 function parameters to  change the look of table that you can see in the output provided at the bottom.

> **Customizing tables using optional parameters**
>
> `spaces`» Number of spaces before and after cell values. Default is `1`.
>
> `fill_char`» Charater to be used to join the 2 joints/corners. Default is `-`.
>
> `corner_char`» A character used at joints or corners of calender table. default is `+`.

Please have a look at the below code.

```
def show_formatted_calendar(no_of_days, sun_starts_from, spaces=1, fill_char='-', corner_char='+'):
    days = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
    blank_fields = 0; # Blank fields in first row(may vary in range [1, 6])

    if not(no_of_days >= 28 and no_of_days <= 31):
        print 'Input Error: Number of days should be in interval [28, 31].';
        return;

    if not(sun_starts_from >= 1 and sun_starts_from <= 7):
        print 'Input Error: Sunday should be inin interval [1, 7].'
        return;

    string = fill_char*spaces; # -
    decorator_line = string + 3 * fill_char + string; # -----
    separator_line = (corner_char + decorator_line) * 7 + corner_char; # +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

    # First line
    formatted_calendar = separator_line + '\n'; 

    # Second line
    line_spaces = ' ' * spaces;
    days_string = "|" + line_spaces + (line_spaces + '|' + line_spaces).join(days) + line_spaces + '|';
    formatted_calendar += days_string + '\n';

    # Third line
    formatted_calendar += separator_line + '\n';

    # Fourth line (No of possible blank fields at the begining)
    blank_fields = (8 - sun_starts_from) % 7; # 1=>0, 2=>6, 3=>5, 4=>4, 5=>5, 6=>2
    blank_string  = (('|' + line_spaces) + (3 * ' ') + line_spaces) * blank_fields;
    date_string = '';

    i = blank_fields + 1;
    day = 1;
    while day <= no_of_days:
        date_string += '|' + line_spaces + '%-3s' % (day) + line_spaces;

        if i % 7 == 0:
            date_string += '|\n';

        i += 1;
        day += 1;

    # No of possible blank fields in last line 
    last_blank_fields = 7 - ((no_of_days - (7 - blank_fields)) % 7); 
    last_blank_string = ('|' + line_spaces + 3 * ' ' + line_spaces) * last_blank_fields + '|';

    formatted_calendar += (blank_string + date_string) + last_blank_string + '\n';
    formatted_calendar += separator_line + '\n'; 

    return  formatted_calendar;

# Starts here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        no_of_days = int(raw_input('Enter number of days of month(>=28 & <=31) : ').strip());
        sun_starts_from = int(raw_input('Sunday starts from which date(>=1 & <=7)   : ').strip());

        # First call
        formatted_calendar = show_formatted_calendar(no_of_days, sun_starts_from);
        print formatted_calendar;

        # Second call (static input)
        print "\nFor Days 31 days where sunday starts from 4:-\n"
        formatted_calendar = show_formatted_calendar(31, 4, 2, '*', '.');
        print formatted_calendar;

        # Third call (static input)
        print "\nFor Days 29 days where sunday starts from 2:-\n"
        formatted_calendar = show_formatted_calendar(29, 2, 3, '~');
        print formatted_calendar;
    except Exception as error:
            print 'Error occurred. ', error;
```

Output »

```
H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\Sof\MonthTableGen>python MonthTableGen.py
Enter number of days of month(>=28 & <=31) : 31
Sunday starts from which date(>=1 & <=7)   : 6
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     | 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   |
| 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 10  | 11  | 12  |
| 13  | 14  | 15  | 16  | 17  | 18  | 19  |
| 20  | 21  | 22  | 23  | 24  | 25  | 26  |
| 27  | 28  | 29  | 30  | 31  |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+


For Days 31 days where sunday starts from 4:-

.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.
|  SUN  |  MON  |  TUE  |  WED  |  THU  |  FRI  |  SAT  |
.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.
|       |       |       |       |  1    |  2    |  3    |
|  4    |  5    |  6    |  7    |  8    |  9    |  10   |
|  11   |  12   |  13   |  14   |  15   |  16   |  17   |
|  18   |  19   |  20   |  21   |  22   |  23   |  24   |
|  25   |  26   |  27   |  28   |  29   |  30   |  31   |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.*******.


For Days 29 days where sunday starts from 2:-

+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+
|   SUN   |   MON   |   TUE   |   WED   |   THU   |   FRI   |   SAT   |
+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+
|         |         |         |         |         |         |   1     |
|   2     |   3     |   4     |   5     |   6     |   7     |   8     |
|   9     |   10    |   11    |   12    |   13    |   14    |   15    |
|   16    |   17    |   18    |   19    |   20    |   21    |   22    |
|   23    |   24    |   25    |   26    |   27    |   28    |   29    |
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~+
```